# is there a better way of combining this?

Tags: posts, categories, get-posts

Hoping someone can point me in the direction of writing this in a more succinct way.

I'm working on my website, and want to display a total of 5 posts from the category 'general wonderings'.

The first post has different styling from the other 4. Please see code below,

Now, 2 problems... they way I've written it means that there is a duplicate post and secondly - surely there's a better way of combining this into one, rather than the way I've written it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
    <div class="columns">
      <?php
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'General Wonderings', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <article>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a></h3>
        <h4>
          <?php the_date(); ?>
        </h4>
        <p>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></p>
      </article>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <?php
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'General Wonderings', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <article>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
          <br/>
          <span><?php echo substr($post->post_excerpt, 0,30); ?>...<br/>
          <?php the_date(); ?>
          </span></a></h4>
      </article>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `offset=1` to exclude first post.

```
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'General Wonderings', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'offset' => 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats'a great help. Regarding the way I've written the rest of the PHP - is that ok? It feels a bit clumsy to me - I'm not great at PHP

Comment: Yeah, rest of the PHP looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I would worry more about performance than succinct code-- shortened it up a little though. Right now you are running two queries. That is not necessary, and that is the biggest issue with this code in my opinion.

```
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'General Wonderings', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
$first = true; ?>
<div class="columns"><?php
foreach($lastposts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <article><?php
    if ($first) { ?>
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a></h3>
      <h4>
       <?php the_date(); ?>
      </h4>
      <p>
       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </p>
      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></p>
      </div><div class="columns"><?php // close the first div and open the second
      $first = false;
    } else { ?>
      <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <br/>
        <span><?php echo substr($post->post_excerpt, 0,30); ?>...<br/>
          <?php the_date(); ?>
        </span></a>
      </h4><?php
    } ?>
    </article><?php
} ?>
</div>
```

Hopefully I preserved the formatting and don't have any syntax errors :)

Comment: Thank you! I think I see what you've done here. It seems to be working, the only issue now that for some reason, there is an empty <div class="column"></div> being rendered. Not sure whether this is related to the updated code or not...

Comment: I think it was an issue with the excerpt - all seems ok now. Thank you!

Comment: Actually - the code above is generating a new <div class="column"> for every new post. Sorry my fault, I should have been clearer. The first article (main one) is to appear in its own column, but then the remaining 4 need to be in the same column.

Comment: So shuffle the `<div` around. It is pretty trivial change.

Comment: Edited the answer